# React - How do I remove array item from state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

In my react app, I have created a page named **Add Product** with a button named **Add Variation** to allow adding small, medium, large variations of a product but can't figure out how to remove the small, medium, or large variation object from the state if user changes their mind.

Here's a summary of the problem:
[image]

Here's what the component looks like now:

```
const AddProduct = () => {
    const [addVar, setAddVar] = useState(0)
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: "",
        description: "",
        categories: [],
        category: "",
        photo: "",
        loading: false,
        error: "",
        createdProduct: "",
        redirectToProfile: false,
        variations: [],
        formData: ""
    });

    const {
        name,
        description,
        price,
        categories,
        category,
        photo,
        loading,
        error,
        createdProduct,
        redirectToProfile,
        variations,
        formData
    } = values;

    const addVariation = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setAddVar(addVar + 1)
        let oldV = Array.from(variations); // gets current variations
        let n = oldV.length; // get current array position
        console.log(`Current number of variations is: ${n}`);
        let vPost = [{ 
            number: n,
            vname: "",
            vprice: "",
            vquantity: "",
            vshipping: ""
        }]  
        let newV = oldV.concat(vPost);         
        setValues({
            ...values,
            variations: newV,
            error: ""
        })
    }   

    const handleVariationChange = (name, numberVal) => event => {
        // numberVal is the iteration number
        // name is the variation property which can be vname, vprice, vshipping, vquantity
        // these are tested next in the following if statements
        const value = event.target.value;
        console.log(`numberVal: `, numberVal);
        event.preventDefault()
        let newVariations = Array.from(variations)
                
        if(name === "vname") { 
            newVariations[numberVal].vname = value;
            console.log(`newVariations[numberVal].vname value: `, newVariations)
        }

        if(name === "vprice") { 
            newVariations[numberVal].vprice = value;
            console.log(`newVariations[numberVal].vprice value: `, newVariations)
        }

        if(name === "vshipping") { 
            newVariations[numberVal].vshipping = value;
            console.log(`newVariations[numberVal].vshipping value: `, newVariations)
        }

        if(name === "vquantity") { 
            newVariations[numberVal].vquantity = value;
            console.log(`newVariations[numberVal].vquantity value: `, newVariations)            
        }
        
        setValues({...values, variations: newVariations})
        formData.set("variations", JSON.stringify(newVariations));
    };

    const removeVariation = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let newVariations = Array.from(variations)
        let popped = newVariations.pop()
        
        setValues({
            ...values,
            variations: newVariations,
            error: ""
        })
        
    }

    const newPostForm = () => (
        <form className="mb-3" onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
            <h4>Main Photo</h4>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="btn btn-secondary">
                    <input
                        onChange={handleChange("photo")}
                        type="file"
                        name="photo"
                        accept="image/*"
                    />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Main Product Name</label>
                <input
                    onChange={handleChange("name")}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={name}
                    placeholder="Add main product name"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Description</label>
                <textarea
                    onChange={handleChange("description")}
                    className="form-control"
                    value={description}
                    placeholder="Add description"
                />
            </div>         
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Category</label>
                <select
                    onChange={handleChange("category")}
                    className="form-control"
                >
                    <option>Please select</option>
                    {categories &&
                        categories.map((c, i) => (
                            <option key={i} value={c._id}>
                                {c.name}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <button onClick={addVariation}>Add variation</button>
                    </div>
                    {variations ? VariationComponent() : null}
            <br />
            <br />
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary">Create Product</button>
        </form>
    );

return (
        <Layout>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                    {newPostForm()}                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default AddProduct;
```

Every time **Add variation** is clicked, another `VariationComponent` form is appended to the page .  For example, if *Add variation* button was clicked 3 times, it would result in 3 `VariationComponent` forms with 3 attached *Remove variation* buttons.  Unfortunately, I do not see how to tell React the position of the #2 item in `variations` to remove it so I resorted to solving this with `.pop()`, which is not what I want.

How can I tell React to remove the right array item when **Remove variation** button is clicked?

Comment: In general, use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead of `pop` when you want to remove an element at a given index. But I'm really struggling to understand how your code works at all. In several places you reference a `variations` variable which seems to not be defined - the relevant array only exists as a property of the `values` state object.

Comment: Actually, instead of `splice` which mutates (as does `pop`), you're better off using `filter` to return a new array which is missing the one with the desired index.

Comment: @RobinZigmond My apologies, on second look I realized I left out the part where I deconstruct the state values and make them available in scope.  Please see again my updated answer.

Comment: @RobinZigmond ok I'm with you on `filter` but how would I use it here?  If I change the button and pass in the `i` like so <button onClick={removeVariation(i)} className="btn-danger">{`Remove Variation`}</button>, then it throws error.  In fact, I have been unable to call the handler with an argument and that's where I'm stuck.  I want to filter but couldn't yet solve how to pass in the position.

Comment: please correct me if i'm wrong, but it seems like you have a single "remove" button that could remove any of three "variations" that you have. it seems like it'd be more appropriate to have possibly a "remove" button for each "variation" that maps the index to your `removeVariation` function, your onClick handler could look like `<button onClick={() => removeVariation(i)}>Remove variation</button>`

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes I think filter is what he wants, but also slice could be used which is also immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RobinZigmond's and @7iiBob's answers, I was able to solve this by this code:

```
    const removeVariation = (e, num) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      
        setValues({
          ...values,
          variations: variations.filter(item => item.number !== num),
          error: ''
        });
      };
```

Remove variation button:

```
<button onClick={(e) => removeVariation(e, variations[i].number)} className="btn-danger">
    {`Remove Variation`}
</button>
```

Keep in mind the empty variation object looks like this:

```
        { 
            number: n,
            vname: "",
            vprice: "",
            vquantity: "",
            vshipping: ""
        }
```

and `n` is coming from `addVariation` here:

```
    const addVariation = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setAddVar(addVar + 1)
        let oldV = Array.from(variations); // gets current variations
        let n = oldV.length; // get current array position
        console.log(`Current number of variations is: ${n}`);
        let vPost = [{ 
            number: n,
            vname: "",
            vprice: "",
            vquantity: "",
            vshipping: ""
        }]  
        let newV = oldV.concat(vPost);         
        setValues({
            ...values,
            variations: newV,
            error: ""
        })
    }
```

Wholehearted thank you as this cost me hours of headache!

Comment: Apologies, I went away for a while - but happy that you've figured it out yourself

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use Arrray.filter() determine which variation to remove. It returns a new array with all but the matching numberVal.

```
onClick={e=>removeVariation(e)}

const removeVariation = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  setValues({
    ...values,
    variations: variations.filter(item => item.name !== e.target.value),
    error: ''
  });
};
```

Comment: Could you share how you would be calling it from onClick?  I tried this but it removes everything in the array.  I am still using `onClick={removeVariation}` but I realize now I could be passing in the position like this: `onClick={() => removeVariation(i)}` tho then I get a `TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function`

Comment: It's difficult to understand why you define `handleVariationChange`, but then use `handleChange`, but either way, I think what you want to use is either `Array.filter()` or `Array.slice()`.

Comment: it's due to handleChange creating the name, category, and photo of the main item but handleVariationChange is solely populating the `variations` array.  variations is a property on the main item document sitting in a `products` collection and uses ObjectId to reference the `variations` collection. These  `variations` ultimately become separate documents in the `variations` collection in mongodb and I `.populate("variations")` when calling it in my /shop page

Comment: I update my answer, but basically, I would pass `e` into onChange, then you can check for the attributes using `e.target.name` or `e.target.value`. That way you don't have to pass each string into onChange by hand as you have already distinguished the different elements by the jsx attributes. Do you understand?

Comment: I've got it working!  Here's what ultimately worked: `onClick={(e) => removeVariation(e, variations[i].number)}`

Comment: Here is the updated `removeVariation` which ultimately worked, based on your answer :)  `    const removeVariation = (e, num) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      
        setValues({
          ...values,
          variations: variations.filter(item => item.number !== num),
          error: ''
        });
      };`

Comment: Awesome. Yeah, sorry I didn't fully understand, but I knew enough that you needed to use something like filter!